# How to record videos and get its path with flutter?

Tags: flutter, camera

I need to access the camera to record videos and get its path so that I can upload them to firebase storage, I tried `Camera plugin`, but threw this error `The getter 'height' was called on null.`  , any ideas how ?

**Code For Camera Plugin**

```
initializeCamera() async {
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    final firstCamera = cameras.first;
    cameraController = CameraController(firstCamera, ResolutionPreset.medium);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeCamera();
    super.initState();
  }

return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _future,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: cameraController.value.aspectRatio,
              child: CameraPreview(cameraController),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: What is the line that's throwing the error ? I don't see any height value being used.

Comment: I think the aspect ratio of the camera controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so simple, I just Had to initialize the camera before anything :).

```
initializeCamera() async {
    await cameraController.initialize();
    final cameras = await availableCameras();
    final firstCamera = cameras.first;
    cameraController = CameraController(firstCamera, ResolutionPreset.medium);
  }
```